# Is ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE supported for DB2 8.2.4 for AIX?

Tags: aix, db2

I am trying to expand a column from SMALLINT to BIGINT.
I get the error:
SQL0104N An unexpected token "BIGINT" was found following ""TYPE SET DATA TYPE". Expected tokens may include:"". SQLSTATE=42601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the DB2 reference for [Alter Table](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000888.htm) you can only alter string (VARCHAR) related data types.

The alternative is to add a new column `TEMP` of type BIGINT, copy the value from column A to column TEMP, rename A to OLD, rename the TEMP to A, and finally drop OLD.

Comment: This suggested solution won't work on DB2 8.2 either, because you can't use ALTER TABLE to drop a column.  You have to drop and recreate the table.  (Or create a second copy of the table and rename the tables).